# Can't display Twitch API data using PHP

Tags: php, twitch

I want to display the last 100 followers on Twitch using their API on my website. However, I know very little about JSON.

Currently I have this:

```
$string = file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/pewdiepie/follows.json?limit=100");
$json=json_decode($string,true);
```

But I can't get it in a while loop.

I tried this:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value){
echo  $value['name'];
}
```

Can someone help me? I just want the last 100 follower names displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that getting the data works, this should do it:

```
foreach ($json['follows'] as $follow){
    echo  $follow['user']['name'];
}
```